# Update @timetamp field in logstash with custom timestamp value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

I have following logstash config file for parsing following exception stack trace.

stacktrace

```
2015-03-02 09:01:51,040 [com.test.MyClass] ERROR - execution resulted in Exception
com.test.core.MyException
    <exception line1>
    <exception line2>
2015-03-02 09:01:51,040 [com.test.MyClass] ERROR - Encountered Exception, terminating execution
```

Config File:

```
input {
stdin {}
}

filter {
  multiline {
      pattern => "(^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) | (^.+Exception+) | (^.+Error+)"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
}

output {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am able to parse stack trace into single logstash field name **message**. However i want update the **@timestamp** with timestamp of first exception line i.e. **2015-03-02 09:01:51,040**

Currently it has been taking default timestamp for **@timestamp**

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `GROK` filter to extract the time value and then use `DATE` filter parse the value into **@timestamp**

For example:

```
input {
        stdin {
                codec => multiline {
                        pattern => "(^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) | (^.+Exception+) | (^.+Error+)"
                        negate => true
                        what => "previous"
                }
        }
}

filter {

        grok {
                match => ["message" , "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"]
        }

        date {
                match => ["logtime", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
        }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Beside, use the multiline in the input instead of in filter is, the multiline in filter will collapse the message into an message array, instead of a single mesage string. So, it will cause grok and date filter failed.

Comment: if you use filebeat as input to logstash you might want to delete first the @timestamp field filebeat adds by default. Like this: grok {
match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} %{GREEDYDATA:content}" }
}
date {
remove_field => [ "%{@timestamp}" ]
match => ["logtime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
} You can chek it here too: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-beats/issues/33#issuecomment-262310842